# changing rails version within a ruby work file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new using both ruby and Ubuntu's terminal(Ubuntu 16.04) , when i downloaded bundle in a work file and accessed http://Localhost:3000 it says unable to connect , a friend told me that the rails version (in this case rails 4.2.6) is at fault so I wanted to change the version to ruby 5, how do I do that?
I used

> gem 'rails','5.1.1'

but it responded me with

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Command Line Error)
>       Unknown command rails,5.1.1

, are there any commands in the terminal I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried bundle install

Comment: you can run: rails update system.... though this will also update other gems to be compatible with the rails 5